# Historischer Gebrauch des Begriffs "Kanakermann"

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Laut [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanake_%28Schimpfwort%29) soll das Schimpfwort "Kanake" aus dem seemännischen Ehrentitel "Kanakermann" stammen:

> Kannakermann war im späten 19. Jahrhundert unter deutschen Seemännern eine verbreitete Bezeichnung für Kameraden aus Polynesien oder Ozeanien. Da diese im Ruf standen, besonders fähige und treue Kameraden zu sein, wurde dieser Begriff sowohl für diese Gruppe meist im positiven Sinne und oft auch als „Ehrentitel“ für besonders gute Kameraden europäischer Herkunft gebraucht. Dies war beispielsweise schon vor dem Zweiten Weltkrieg in Süddeutschland und Österreich als alter Kanaker in dem gleichen Sinn üblich wie die norddeutsche Bezeichnung alter Schwede.

Ich zweifle nicht daran, dass der Schimpfname aus dem polynesischen Sprachgebrauch kommt. Die Nebenbehauptung, dass "Kanakermann" als gebräuchliches Wort galt, finde ich aber wenig überzeugend. Diese Erklärung ist überall im Internet zu finden, aber die einzige Quelle dafür ist ein Artikel von Gabriele Trost ("Bezeichnet das Wort "Kanake" die nach Deutschland eingewanderten Türken?" - 31.10.2011 [Planet Wissen](http://www.planet-wissen.de/alltag_gesundheit/gastarbeiter_und_migration/geschichte_der_gastarbeiter/wissensfrage_kanake.jsp)), da fehlt aber eine Literaturangabe, die dies untermauert. Mit Google Ngram werden komischerweise keine Treffer gefunden. Außerdem sind alle Treffer bei Google-Suchen nur Variationen des oben erwähnten Wikipedia Eintrags.

Gibt es irgendwelche handfesten Beweise, die diese Erklärung unterstützen? Hat man schon mal von "Kanakermann" gelesen bzw. gehört?

Comment: Noch nie gehört. Für den Sprachgebrauch der Gegenwart ist _Kanak(e)_ ausschließlich abwertend zu verstehen.

Comment: Eigentlich drängt sich eher die Herleitung "Polyneser mit dunkler Hautfarbe" -> "Mensch mit dunkler Hautfarbe" -> "Südländer, Ausländer" auf, oder?

Comment: Ich habe das Wort auch vorher noch nie gelesen oder gehört.

Comment: @dirkt Das lässt sich besser eingehen. Allerdings gibt es nur sehr wenige Literatur, die über die Etymologie des Wortes Aufschluss gibt. Ich habe zur Hand leider kein etymologisches Wörterbuch, aber ich glaube nicht, dass es dazu einen Eintrag geben wird. The mystery continues...

Comment: Wenn "Kannakermann" wirklich mal unter Seemännern (wahrscheinlich nicht sehr lange) als "Modewort" in Gebrauch war, wird es auch verdammt schwierig sein, dazu Belege zu finden. Da muss man wahrscheinlich ausgiebig Primärquellen selbst lesen, bis man etwas findet. Und ich denke immer noch, dass der heutige Gebrauch von "Kanake" eher davon unabhängig ist (s.o.), und wahrscheinlich irgendjemand in Wikipedia wieder mal seine/ihre eigene Lieblingstheorie in Umlauf bringen wollte.

Comment: Hier ist ein interessanter Artikel: https://www.welt.de/kultur/article154409100/Wie-Kanake-zum-rassistischen-Hasswort-wurde.html

Answer (score 3):

Die Bezeichnung *Kanakermann* mag vielleicht aus einer seltenen Quelle stammen, eine Referenz für die Verwendung dieses Kompositums habe ich aber nicht finden können.

Das Wort [Kanak/Kanake](http://www.dwds.de/?kompakt=1&qu=kanake) selbst stammt offenbar aus dem Polynesischen und hat sich erst in der zweiten Hälfte des 20. Jahrhunderts zu einem abwertenden Begriff für Einwanderer nach Deutschland entwickelt:

> **Kanake** *m.* ‘Südseeinsulaner, Polynesier’, zuerst von Seeleuten entlehnt (19. Jh.) aus polynes. *kanaka* ‘Mensch’. Die Bezeichnung wird (Mitte 20. Jh.) in der Vulgärsprache teilweise zur Selbstbezeichnung von Migranten, vor allem aber zum Schmähwort für Leute fremder Herkunft oder fremdländischen Aussehens.

Im 19. Jahrhundert kann man den Begriff gelegentlich in (Reise-)Berichten über die Südsee finden. Darin wird ein Eingeborener einer Südseeinsel als **[Kanake](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanak_%28Volk%29)** bezeichnet, schon damals meist in abwertender und rassistischer Verwendung:

Beispiele:

> - Die Eingeborenen haben bereits vielfach beweisen, dass ein **Kanak** ein intelligenter und fleißiger Mensch sein und auch seine Lebenweise ganz auf europäisch einrichten könne.<sup>[Unsere Zeit, 13. Heft 1871](http://books.google.de/books?id=eJhTAAAAcAAJ&hl=de&pg=PP5#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>
> - Das Schiff segelt nach irgend einer der Inseln wo man sich **Kanaken** verschaffen zu können glaubt, und bei der Ankunft an dem Orte seiner Bestimmung verliert man keine Zeit sich mit den Eingeborenen in Verbindung zu setzen, die gemeiniglich in Canoes schaarenweise den neunen Ankömmlingen entgegen sahen. <sup>[Das Ausland, 1870](http://books.google.de/books?id=tk1EAAAAcAAJ&hl=de&pg=PR1#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>
> - So sind z.B. die **Kanaken** in einigen Gegenden der Ostküste sehr gut und kräftig gebaut; sie haben tüchtige Knochen und Muskeln, sind niemals übermäßig wohlbeleibt, und ihre Brustbildung läßt nichts zu wünschen übrig; dagegen haben sie, wie die Neu-Kaledonier überhaupt, zu dünne Beine, und die Waden liegen höher als bei den Europäern.<sup>[Das neue Buch der Reisen und Entdeckungen, 1873](http://books.google.de/books?id=TuFaAAAAcAAJ&hl=de&pg=PP6#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>
> - Die gemeinen Insulaner, welche **Kanaken** heißen, werden von der bevorrechteten Kaste gleich Sclaven gehalten und stehen körperlich und geistig auf einer niedern Stufe der Ausbildung.<sup>[Magazin der neuesten Reisen und Läderbeschreibungen, 1840](http://books.google.de/books?id=EiAWAAAAYAAJ&hl=de&pg=PR2#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>

Comment: Obwohl die Infos hier sehr interessant sind, bleibt die Frage noch offen. Es weckt eigentlich noch mehr Zweifel, dass das Wort Kanak(e) offenbar in Reiseberichten oft vorkam, obwohl "Kanakermann" nirgendwo zu finden ist. Vielleicht kann man diese Frage hier nicht gleich beantworten. Ich werde mehr dazu nachforschen. Nun eine Frage des Protokolls: soll ich diese Antwort akzeptieren und später bei Gelegenheit mit weiteren Infos bearbeiten? Wie läuft das mit Fragen dieser Art?

Comment: @Milchgesicht: eine Referenz zum Gebrauch von "Kanakermann" wäre wirklich interessant. Falls jemand oder du eine findet, ist das eine weitere Antwort wert, die du dann akzeptieren kannst (auch wenn es deine eigene ist!).

Answer (score 2):

Tja, ich habe keine auswertbaren Quellen, aber ein Seemann, dem ich vor etwa 30 Jahren mal in einer unangenehmen Situation half, hat mich als "Guter Kanakermann" bezeichnet. Also sollte ja irgendwas dran sein. Mehr kann ich dazu nicht sagen, und ich trage die Bezeichnung gern, obwohl ich nicht aus den benannten Regionen stamme.